# shut iMac display off but keep ubuntu server running in background

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04 on my iMac G4. Is there a way to have the screen turn off ('sleep' the display as in Mac OS X), and turn back on automatically from something like any key being pressed? The screen goes black after a couple minutes, but I want it to go completely off.

I don't want to have to install a graphical UI; I want to stick with the command line (if possible). I'm extremely new to Ubuntu/unix stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the framebuffer driver your kernel is using to drive the iMac's graphics hardware supports it, this should power the monitor off after 10+10 minutes:

```
setterm -blank 10
setterm -powersave on
setterm -powerdown 10
```

I don't remember if Ubuntu has an configurable rc script that calls `setterm` at boot.

If that doesn't work, try (at your own risk) poking the hardware directly, one of:

```
vbetool dpms off
vbetool vbefp setbrightness 0
```

Comment: ...how do I run the commands? (at startup, correct?)

Comment: @sman591: http://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior/152349#152349

Answer (score 0):

Got the display to turn off on an iMac Pro Ubuntu Server 22.04

First `startx` must be executed and be running on the main host, I usually execute it on the local machine itself and the log in via a ssh session

```
xrandr
ls /tmp/.X11-unix
export DISPLAY=:0
xrandr --query
xrandr --output eDP --off
```